# Undefined function or method 'readimage' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load an image but it is showing the error message `Undefined function or method 'readimage' for input arguments of type 'char'.`

My calling function is here

```
 h=uicontrol(FigWin,...
 'Style','pushbutton',...
 'Position',[0,320,80,20],...
 'String','Load',...
 'Callback',...
 ['image1=loadimage;'...
 'subplot(AxesHandle1);'...
 'imagesc(image1);'...
 'title(textLoad);'...
 'colormap(gray);']);
```

My called function is below

```
function image1=loadimage
    [imagefile1 , pathname]= uigetfile('*.bmp;*.BMP;*.tif;*.TIF;*.jpg','Open An Fingerprint image'); 
    if imagefile1 ~= 0 
        cd(pathname);
        image1=readimage(char(imagefile1));
        image1=255-double(image1);
    end
end
```

Another question, if there are warnings in the program is it a problem?  Sorry, i am new to Matlab. Thank you.

Comment: There is no function named readimage in MATLAB. Have you defined your own? Or you could try using [imread](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you. my readimage function is like `function b = readimage(w)
a=imread(w);
b = double(a);
`

Comment: Please run `which readimage` in the Matlab command window to check whether the function is visible on the path. If not, change directory to wherever you have stored readimage, or add that directory to the path (in the menu File).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this only as a path issue.

The problem is almost certainly that `readimage.m` isn't on the path, but was/is instead located in the current directory you tested it from.  Right now the easiest solution would be to use `imread` directly instead of your straight wrapper `readimage`, but assuming you want to add functionality to `readimage` later:

The simple solution is to add the directory `readimage.m` to your path (File->Set Path->Add Folder->Browse to directory with readimage.m).  However if you want to test that this is indeed the issue then make sure you can manually run `readimage('existing_image.jpg')` (meaning you should browse to that directory) and then run the following modified code

```
function image1=loadimage
    [imagefile1 , pathname]= uigetfile('*.bmp;*.BMP;*.tif;*.TIF;*.jpg','Open An Fingerprint image'); 
    if imagefile1 ~= 0 
        image1=readimage([pathname imagefile1]);
        image1=255-double(image1);
end;
```

The only difference from the original code is that we're not using cd(pathname) to change the directory, but instead are incorporating it into the readimage command itself.

I'm betting that the combination of the cd() command and it not being on the path combined to make you think that readimage(w) was on the path and working, when it was really just in the current directory... until the cd() command was run.

Answer (score 0):

A slight rewrite of your function:

```
function img = loadimage()
    [fname,pname] = uigetfile('*.bmp;*.tif;*.jpg', 'Open Fingerprint image');
    if pname==0, error('no file selected'); end

    img = imread( fullfile(pname,fname) );
    img = 255 - double(img);
end
```